# Unary relationship with attributes in Barker and UML notations?

Tags: database-design, relational-database, uml, notation

I have a problem with creating database notation and it's about unary relationship with attributes, i know how to draw my database notation in chen because there u can attach attribute to relationship, but I also need to create this in Barker and UML notation, i've read that i can do it by drawing relationship with attributes as an entity but teacher said to me that i need to change it and didn't give me any tip about it(i don't know if there is a way to do so maybe i shouldn't include it in e-r barker and chen notations?), i can't find anything else on the internet or i'm blind, can someone help me with it?

Adding an image on how i made it :

[image]

So the main entity is named pojazd which means vehicle and the relationship with attribute is named jest_czterokolowcem which means is_fourwheeler and if the vehicle is a four wheeler im adding attribute which is color.

The things that I already tried is searching over internet and asking some people

I only need help or explanation on how to draw relationship with attribute in Barker and UML notation

Comment: One of the problems is that your example is just nonsense. Why would color be an attribute of an relation called `is_fourwheeler`? Why would that relation even exist, and to what other entity is related to? Anyway, ignoring all that, I suspect your teacher wants you to use an association class.

Comment: @GeertBellekens this example is nonsense thats true, thanks for your answer i will just try to think about something else then and try to do something with this association class :)

Comment: @GeertBellekens Can You tell me if something like that will be a better relationship with attributes DEPARTMENT =>HAS=>LOCALIZATION those will be two entities and between them there will be relationship with attributes for a specific ADDRESS or something like that, then i will not need o use it as a unary and then i can draw it properly beetween to entities and there will be no problem :)